# Wordpress Woocommerce Reports page issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem,I tested this in my server and everything works fine.
But on live site ( godaddy server ) its not working .

If I click **woocommerce --> reports** it says page not found after loading for 10 seconds.
[image]

And I get this error in console.

*admin.php?page=wc-reports:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

I tested everything , disabled all plugins , move the files from live to my server.

Also I am getting no debug errors.
Does anyone have any ideea on how I can fix this?
Thank You.

Comment: Does WooCommerce-->Settings and WooCommerce --> Status work?

Comment: Did you found something in the server error logs?

Comment: @user141080  for some reason i managed to fix this ,now the main problem is the follow up emails plugin is not working.I haven o ideea if you can help me with this . wp-admin/admin.php?page=followup-emails keeps loading and then it shows me page not found for some reason. The only error I see is in console and it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) " , thank you

Comment: @user9372991 see my comment above,  thank you :0